# Save (print) xml node with its parents but without children

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

From the XML document, I want to save one node to a file - with all parent nodes, but without any child nodes. For example, for the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
 <Document id="myid">
  <name>ref.kml</name>
  <Style id="normalState">
     <IconStyle><scale>1.0</scale><Icon><href>yt.png</href></Icon></IconStyle>    
  </Style>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

expected output for `<Document>` node will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
 <Document id="myid">
 </Document>
</kml>
```

So far I only found a solution with iterated removal of all child elements before saving. But as I need to work with original XML after, I have to make a copy of the whole document:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import lxml.etree as ET # have to use [lxml] because [xml] doesn't support 'xml_declaration'
import copy

kml_file = ET.parse("myfile.kml")
kml_copied = copy.deepcopy(kml_file) # .copy() is not enough, need .deepcopy()
root = kml_copied.getroot()
my_node = root[0]
for child in my_node:
    my_node.remove(child)
print ET.tostring(kml_copied, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Is there better way to do this? at least to avoid making a deepcopy of the whole document...

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), the special-purpose declarative language designed to transform XML documents. And Python's lxml module has a built-in XSLT 1.0 processor. Additionally XSLT (whose script is a well-formed xml document can also adequately handle the kml undeclared namespace):

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl to be loaded in Python, also portable to other languages)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:doc="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform to copy entire document -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Empty Template to Remove Nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="doc:Style|doc:name"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL 
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM INPUT INTO DOM OBJECT
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUT DOM TO STRING
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom,
                       encoding='UTF-8',
                       pretty_print=True,
                       xml_declaration=True)
print(tree_out.decode("utf-8"))

# SAVE RESULTING XML
xmlfile = open('Output.xml','wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
  <Document id="myid"/>
</kml>
```

Comment: well, I thought that launching XSLT machinery for so simple task would be a bit overkill :) But I will consider it, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Do note, other XML modifications can be handled in same XSLT script in addition to removal of nodes. And you can embed the XSLT inside Python instead of external file. Plus, file is portable to other languages and executables (Java, PHP, C#, VBA, Saxon, Xalan). Surely, a scalable answer! If helpful, please accept to confirm resolution.